# How can I do d3 without this to support JSLint

Tags: javascript, d3.js, jslint

How to convert below code as valid JSLint code i.e. (dont use **this** keyword)
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eGGXKR

```js
d3.selectAll(".test").style("background-color", function(){
  return d3.select(this).html();
})
```

```css
.test{
  padding:4px;
  margin:4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.9.1/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">red</div>
<div class="test">green</div>
<div class="test">blue</div>
<div class="test">pink</div>
<div class="test">yellow</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a D3 method, like `style()`, `this` is the same of the third and second arguments combined.

So, this...

```
d3.selectAll(".test").style("background-color", function(){
    return d3.select(this).html();
})
```

.... is the same of:

```
d3.selectAll(".test").style("background-color", function(d,i,n){
    return d3.select(n[i]).html();
})
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
d3.selectAll(".test").style("background-color", function(d,i,n){
  return d3.select(n[i]).html();
})
```

```css
.test{
  padding:4px;
  margin:4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.9.1/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">red</div>
<div class="test">green</div>
<div class="test">blue</div>
<div class="test">pink</div>
<div class="test">yellow</div>
```